# Getting blank lemmatization using xx_use_lg model with Spacy Python

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, lemmatization

I got a list of words using `for element in text: print(element)`.

But when I try to use **lemma_** like this (`for element in text: print(element.lemma_)`) it returns me blank list.

I can't understand why this append. But it probably comes because I'm using `xx_use_lg` model from Spacy. And so I can't do anything about it.

But if you have some solution to this problem thank you in advance !

I tried changing the input as String and also as List but still getting same blank list returning.

I tried before doing this work with another model than xx_.._.. and it worked. But I need absolutely to use xx_use_lg.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of how you're using the model to create `text`. It is likely that you're not calling the full spaCy pipeline on it to generate the lemmas.

Comment: Lemmatization is heavily language dependent, but the `xx` pipeline is specifically multi-language. Trying to lemmatize a word without knowing what language it's in doesn't make any sense. You will have to configure / train your own lemmatizer, but I'm not sure a reasonable way to do that exists in the first place, and you haven't given enough information here to determine one. Why do you have to use the `xx` pipeline?

Comment: I have to use xx pipeline because I wan't to work on french words. But also determines if there are some potential errors in the text & or joinedwords. That also might be in other languages. I am actually sending a **string text** in a function I apply stopwords to this text and then trying to get lemmatization.

Comment: The section between "********" caracter is the specific one which don't works.

`tokens_without_sw = [word for word in text_tokens if not word in all_stopwords]


    for ent in reversed(tokens_without_sw): 
        if (len(ent) < 3):
            tokens_without_sw.remove(ent)
        if (len(ent) >= 15):
            tokens_without_sw.remove(ent)

    tokens_without_sw = ' '.join(tokens_without_sw)

    tokens = list(nlp(str(tokens_without_sw)))

    *********************************
    for element in tokens:
        print(element)
*********************************`

Comment: Here : `print(element)` is working fine and makes me a list of all words inside tokens. But when I try to apply `print(element.lemma_)` Here I got the blank list.